# tensorFlow serving batch configure ineffectiveness

Tags: tensorflow-serving

**docker run command**

```
docker run -t --rm -p 8500:8500 -p 8501:8501 
-v /home/zhi.wang/tensorflow-serving/model:/models 
-e MODEL_NAME=beidian_cart_ctr_wdl_model tensorflow/serving:1.12.0 
--enable_batching=true --batching_parameters_file=/models/batching_parameters.txt &
```

**batching_parameters.txt**

```
num_batch_threads { value: 40 }
batch_timeout_micros { value: 5000}
max_batch_size {value: 20000000}
```

**server configuration**

40 cpu and 64G memory

**test result**

1 thread predict cost 30ms
40 thread predict one predict cost 300ms

**cpu usage**

cpu usage in docker can only up to 300% and host cpu usage is low

**java test script**

```java
TensorProto.Builder tensor = TensorProto.newBuilder();

tensor.setTensorShape(shapeProto);

tensor.setDtype(DataType.DT_STRING);
// batch set 200 
for (int i=0; i<200; i++) {
    tensor.addStringVal(example.toByteString());
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

i also face the same proble and i found that's maybe the network io problem,you can use dstat to monitor your network interface.

and i fount example.toByteString() also cost much time